# How to select from line to line in vi?

Tags: text, vim, text-editor, vi

I frequently want to select multiple lines in vi.  e.g. from line 1 to line 10.

So, what I usually do when I want to jump from line to line is I type `:110` to jump to line `110`, e.g.

And, when I want to select from line to line, I usually press `v` to get into visual mode, and then I just scroll down using `k` or `l`.

So, intuitively it makes sense to me to just press `v`, and then type `:<line number>`.  but that doesn't work.

How to select from line X to line Y in vi?

Comment: In vi or in Vim?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's assume you want to highlight from line 10 to line 20. You can use:

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Breakdown:

- <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> enters `10` into the buffer
- <kbd>G</kbd> goes to the line number in the buffer
- <kbd>V</kbd> enters visual line mode
- <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> enters `20` into the buffer
- <kbd>G</kbd> goes to the line number in the buffer

Note that <kbd>G</kbd> means <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (capital `G`).

Source and a `:` command are [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43381/select-lines-using-ranges-in-vim).

Answer (score 8):

Selection by itself isn't meaningful; you usually want to invoke a command on the selection. Many commands that work on the visual selection have a corresponding *Ex command*. With that, going through visual mode is unnecessary if you already know the exact ranges. The great benefit of visual mode is that you can interactively and iteratively adapt the selected area if there's no single motion or text object.

The benefit [`:help :range`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#:range) is that you can succinctly specify the lines. For example, lines 110 to 120 can be written as `:110,120`, but also as `:110;+10`.

Answer (score 8):

**simple just press** <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>line number</kbd> <kbd>gg</kbd>

**example**: your current line to line 41
Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>41</kbd> <kbd>gg</kbd>

**note**: you can move to selected line by press <kbd>line number</kbd> <kbd>gg</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

If you set both number and relative number it becomes easy to see the target end line.

```
:set number relativenumber
```

So, let's say you are at the line 10 and the target line shows 11, you start your selection with capital V, then press 11j

```
V11j
```

If your block has blank lines before and after, just type vip (visuall inner paragraph)